# Some font styles are the same after I changed it

Tags: android, fonts, bold, italic

OK, I'm gonna be the most specific as possible. I have an Alcatel One Touch 7042A, black color. This cellphone doesn't include the feature of changing the system font, as it isn't Samsung or LG. I wanted to change it, so I rooted my phone with an app which name is "Kingoroot superuser". The root was a success, then I downloaded a font changer app: "iFont: expert of fonts". There was a big list of fonts, I chose and downloaded "chococooky" which size is of 2.14 MB. I remember that, before applying the font, I had to select a change font mode, which are the next: "Auto (smart match), System mode (need root), Recovery mode, samsung mode, install mode, miui mode and huawei mode". I selected AUTO (SMART MATCH). My phone rebooted and the font applying was a success.
Now comes the problem: Every letter changed, but letters in bold, italic and serif kept the default font. I don't know how to change it, I selected SYSTEM MODE in iFont again but the same. Can you help me? I hope I didn't confuse you with so many details :/

Comment: This question appears to be offtopic because it is a question about getting an Android app to work, and that app has nothing to do with programming anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs, very clearly, [Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: But I'm just saying that I want to change letters in bold, italic and serif because they kept the same and I want them to change to the font I applied to it

Comment: This is a site for progamming related questions, not about customizing rooted android handsets, I have explicitly highlighted the alternative site found on our sister site as mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. And goodbye.

Comment: Goodbye??? And who said that I'm gonna get outta here just for asking for help? I won't go of here never!!! If you thought that then you're wrong, little child. EVERYONE IS WRONG

Comment: No, you know what, I'm going to get outta here because if all the questions that I post, you're going to act as beasts voting the question offtopic and all that shit. Then this site and you are useless nerds. I'm going to look for another site, WHO ANSWERS ALL MY QUESTIONS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font package has come with bold, italic ...?

I think you need to download fonts for each type:

Font X,
Font X Bold,
Font X italic ...

Comment: hey!! I've understood already, I downloaded the complete font and I'll make iFont to install it with all its styles. I owe u one!